# .net - Access Linux directory with C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, linux, windows

I still haven't started this yet - just want to get some ideas, but can I access the directories and files on a Linux machine within a network using a C# Windows Service? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555046/how-to-access-linux-directories-files-from-a-windows-service-using-c-sharp) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/255821/Read-file-from-linux-computer-from-windows-compute), but so far, they are only trying to fetch the files inside the directory. My goal is:

- Read if the files are existing
- We expect the files to be zip files, so we the unzipping should happen on the Linux machine's directory
- The Windows Service is deployed on the Windows machine with a `FileSystemWatcher` that will watch if the files on the Linux directory is created

I've read something about SSH and FTP libraries for C#, but isn't it only for getting the files? I want to interact with the files itself inside the directory.

Any helpful links or answers will be appreciated.

***UPDATE:***

I think one of the requirements is no using of Active Directory - which cancels out use of Samba.

Comment: I think these are two different things: how to make your linux files available on windows and how to access them from C#.

Comment: the files won't be transferred from the Linux environment - the processes will all be on the Linux directory. so we can say I need to access the files, and not make it available on Windows.

Comment: Just to clarify: I suppose that you/your client IS NOT USING Microsoft AD for authentication?

Comment: Yes, he's not using AD.

Comment: @DustineTheGreat: What's the difference between "access files" and "make it available"? To access the files, they need to be available somehow. I didn't say anything about copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Samba setup guide

First update the server and install Samba:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install samba
```

---

Then wget this file: [Samba config](https://www.airpett.com/test/smb.conf).
Open it with your favorite text editor (i.e. nano on vi). REMEMBER TO SUDO THE EDITOR!!!

Find the following lines (and change the parameters to suit your needs):

```
[share]
   comment = A share
   path = /path/to/folder
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = no
   create mask = 0755
```

*comment* is a description for the share.

*path* is the path to the folder to share

*browsable = yes* makes the share and it's content browsable for authenticated users

*guest ok = no* disables anonymous login

*read only = no* enables editing and renaming files

*create mask = 0755* sets the default permissions for new files

---

Then create user (and set password) for accessing the share:

```
sudo useradd share
sudo passwd share
sudo smbpasswd -a share
sudo smbpasswd -e share
```

---

Move your smb.conf to /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
sudo mv smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

---

Reload Samba config:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba reload
```

OR If that doesn't work:

```
sudo smbd reload
```

---

### Done!

Now you can access the share on windows using `\\serverAddress\share`

The username is `WORKGROUP\share` OR `linuxServerHostname\share` and password is the password you set above.

You can now map the share as network drive into Windows by going to explorer and use the "Map Network Drive"-wizard. There tick the checkbox "Connect using different credentials". You can map the network drive with C# as well.

All files and folders in the share now (when mapped) act as local files.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a Samba share on the remote Linux-machine, then the directory will act as a Windows share. Then you'd also be able to map it as a network drive and work with it the same way as local files.

Comment: updated my post. i think the client don't want to use Active Directory, which is integrated by using Samba.

Comment: Actually no, I have a lot of Samba shares at home and without AD.

Comment: "Samba is an important component to seamlessly integrate Linux/Unix Servers and Desktops into Active Directory environments."

quoted from samba.org. not really familiar with Linux, with all honesty, so I'm not sure how it will be implemented.

Comment: This is a good link for making the Samba server: [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide). I'll post another answer with essential details on how to get Samba up and running.