# How can i access shared file in another machine in different Network?

Tags: c#

How can i access remotely the shared folder file in another machine.I was tried like this.

```
 public void LoadExcelData()
{

     string strLogFilePath = @"\\corevodev24.corevo.ind\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Web Server Extensions\\15\\TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\Contact.XLSX";
        string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + strLogFilePath);

    NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(@"robert", "abc123$", "corevo.ind");
    CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache();
    theNetCache.Add(new Uri(@"\\corevodev24.corevo.ind"), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
 //   C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\Contact.XLSX
    System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("\\corevodev24.corevo.ind\\C$\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Web Server Extensions\\15\\TEMPLATE");

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\\corevodev24\C$\SharedFolder\Contact.XLSX", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader str = new StreamReader(@"\\corevodev24\C$\SharedFolder\Contact.XLSX");
```

when i was access the file it was showing access to the path is access denied. someone give me a solution for this i tried lot but same error.The file was stored in another computer.In my system how can i read the Excel file.

My requirement is client system they are having Excel sheet in network shared folder.I want to read that excel file.Someone give me a solution for this.Thank is Advance.

Comment: How are you handling authorization ?Also see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700871/connect-to-network-drive-with-user-name-and-password

Comment: They are giving access to that folder using username and password.File was in shared Folder.