# Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password while create folder in remote machine

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a folder in remote machine which is in same network and when I ping remote machine I'm getting reply also. but when I try to create 
folder and try to copy files I'm getting the error

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password."

Below is the code I m using. Is there any way I can 
pass user name and password to create folder and copy files into remote machine. Suggest me how this can be achieved.

```
string path = @"\\30.120.119.121\c$\RemoteFolder";
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Files");
    foreach (var item in files)
    {
        string file = Path.GetFileName(item);
        File.Copy(item, path+ file);
    }
}
```

Comment: What line throws that error?

Comment: Are you able to do file operation in explorer when you connect to said computer?

Comment: If you are able to access a computer's file share like that, given that is an internet ip (not a local network), then the computer at `30.120.119.121` has some serious security issues that need to be addressed. Just because a machine responds to ICMP does not mean that it is readily exploitable for other operations. To answer your question, you can try this [Access Network Share with Credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22378883/3504007)

Comment: If trying to brute force the machine, this would be why you don't allow file-shares over the internet  :)

Comment: @SumnerEvans, Getting error @   Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

Comment: @n0rd, When i try to open the \\30.120.119.121\c$\  first time it will ask for username and password. after that i m able to copy files and create folder.

Comment: @Ravikumar_n, then you should search for how to access password protected network share, it has been answered numerous times on this site alone. Try the answers then ask for clarifications if it does not help.