# Network file share access in .NetCore

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to access a network file share with .NET Core. I have seen this solution for Net Standard:

[How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share/39540451#39540451)

```
public class NetworkConnection : IDisposable
    {
        string _networkName;

    public NetworkConnection(string networkName, 
        NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        _networkName = networkName;

        var netResource = new NetResource()
        {
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
            RemoteName = networkName
        };

        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
            ? credentials.UserName
            : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

        var result = WNetAddConnection2(
            netResource, 
            credentials.Password,
            userName,
            0);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
        }   
    }

    ~NetworkConnection()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
    }

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource, 
        string password, string username, int flags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
        bool force);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class NetResource
    {
        public ResourceScope Scope;
        public ResourceType ResourceType;
        public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
        public int Usage;
        public string LocalName;
        public string RemoteName;
        public string Comment;
        public string Provider;
    }

    public enum ResourceScope : int
    {
        Connected = 1,
        GlobalNetwork,
        Remembered,
        Recent,
        Context
    };

    public enum ResourceType : int
    {
        Any = 0,
        Disk = 1,
        Print = 2,
        Reserved = 8,
    }

    public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
    {
        Generic = 0x0,
        Domain = 0x01,
        Server = 0x02,
        Share = 0x03,
        File = 0x04,
        Group = 0x05,
        Network = 0x06,
        Root = 0x07,
        Shareadmin = 0x08,
        Directory = 0x09,
        Tree = 0x0a,
        Ndscontainer = 0x0b
    }
```

I have read that using [DllImport("mpr.dll")] in core is not advised. Is there a .net core way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700871/connect-to-network-drive-with-user-name-and-password/22378883 and  look for the answer that says "Very elegant solution inspired from this one. This one uses only .Net library and does not need to use any command line or Win32 API."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleImpersonation/

Using that you can access a file share with a simple :

```
var credentials = new UserCredentials(domain, username, password);
var result = Impersonation.RunAsUser(credentials, logonType, () =>
{
    return System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( @"\\server\share" );
});
```

Comment: Which kind of logonType would be appropriate for access to a share?

Comment: @grek40, depends on the use case. They are explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera - but when impersonating a user, do "what the user would do", and for that purpose I would use INTERACTIVE.

Comment: I used `LogonType.NewCredentials` for QNAP file network sharing

Comment: This is a Windows only solution, does not work on linux or mac.

Comment: I get the error of System.ArgumentException: 'Username cannot contain \ or @ characters when domain is provided separately. (Parameter 'username')'. I have to include \ in he username so how to solve this issue.Below is my code:  UserCredentials credentials = new UserCredentials("111.222.333.45", "ABC\Test.test", "Test@12"); @j0ffe

Answer (score 0):

For running in Linux,
You could use this library. It works for me.
https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary/blob/master/ClientExamples.md

```
//Assuming you want to access //yourServerName.xyz.com/A/B/123.txt
var client = new SMB2Client(); 
var cancelToken = new System.Threading.CancellationToken();
var isConnected = client.ConnectAsync("yourServerName.com", SMBTransportType.DirectTCPTransport, cancelToken).Result;
if (isConnected)
{
     NTStatus status = client.LoginAsync("domain", "username", "password", cancelToken).Result;
     if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
     {
          var shares = client.ListShares(cancelToken).Result;
          //Here you can get the shares then follow above example link to access your file
     }
 }
```