# How to read a file from a Linux server using .net core c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

We have a network drive (OS: Linux) and need to read data files. in Visual studio api runs smooth with this location (\172.x.x.x\folder\file.csv) but when we deploy this in IIS it throws a below error.

> "One or more errors occurred. (The user name or password is incorrect. : '\172.x.x.x\folder\file.csv') (The user name or password is incorrect. : '\172.x.x.x\folder\file.csv')"

Network Location is Linux based enviroment,
Development and Deployment is in IIS

Comment: Visual studio runs as you, IIS app pools do not (by default). Sounds like a permission issue

Comment: It's running as a different user. Use Process Explorer to figure out as who IIS runs and grant him permissions.

Comment: Can you please share IIS Pool Settings ? I have tried all settings but no luck

Comment: Keep in mind it is very easy to introduce a security issue when you just want something to work. You should have a strategy for resource access, but [this is what you want to read about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Comment: You should not be installing file on IIS server for uses to access. Use a File Server instead where you can change access list.  A IIS is meant to be secure so clients have limited access to the IIS System Resource.  Client connect by default with GUEST privilege's.

Comment: @jdweng the question literally says "a network drive" in the first sentence.

Comment: @Crowcoder : it also says when we DEPLOY to IIS.

Comment: @jdweng I take that to mean the application that works from visual studio, not the files.

Comment: @Crowcoder : I can't tell where the Network drive is located.  From description is could be on the IIS server.

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56065529/7687666)