# Copy file to remote computer with C# script and NAnt ( A specified logon session does not exist )

Tags: c#, file, copy, nant, teamcity

I'm currently working on a script (using NAnt and C#) running on a TeamCity server, which is to create and deploy an MSI file on a remote computer. The remote computer is set up with a shared folder which the TeamCity server is to connect to and copy the MSI file into, though the script. And it works the first time I run it without any problem.

But when I run the script a second time, it throws an exception with the following the message when it tries to connect to the share on the remote computer;

```
"A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."
```

I use the solution from [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share) thread to copy the MSI file from the TeamCity server to the remote computer using logon cridentials.

The following is the C# script in my NAnt file which does the file copy:

```
//Script main entry point
public static void ScriptMain(Project project)
{
    NetworkCredential deployTargetCridentials = new NetworkCredential(project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr.username"],
                                                                        project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr.password"]);

    string connection = @"\\" + project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr"] + project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr.sharepath"];

    string sourceFile = project.Properties["wix.output.dir"] + @"\" + project.Properties["wix.output.file"] + ".msi";
    string destinationFile = @"\\" + project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr"] +
                                        project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr.sharepath"] + @"\" +
                                        project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr.deployfile"];

    //Copy installation file to deploy share
    Copy(project
            , project.Properties["wix.output.dir"]
            , project.Properties["wix.output.file"] + ".msi"
            , @"\\" + project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr"] + project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr.sharepath"]
            , project.Properties["deploy.remotesvr.deployfile"]
            , deployTargetCridentials);

    ////
}


//Copy MSI
public static void Copy(Project project, string sourcePath, string sourceFile, string destinationPath, string destinationFile, NetworkCredential cridentials)
{
    string source = sourcePath + @"\" + sourceFile;
    string destination = destinationPath + @"\" + destinationFile;

    try
    {
        project.Log(Level.Info, " ");
        project.Log(Level.Info, "Copying " + source + " to " + destination);

        project.Log(Level.Info, "  Connecting to copy share: " + destinationPath);
        using (new NetworkConnection(destinationPath, cridentials))
        {
            project.Log(Level.Info, "  Copying file");
            File.Copy(source, destination, true);
        }
        project.Log(Level.Info, "Copy successfull!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        project.Log(Level.Warning, "WARNING: Could not copy file: " + ex.Message.ToString().Trim().Replace("\r\n", ""));
    }
}


////


//NetworkConnection class
public class NetworkConnection : IDisposable
{
    string _networkName;

    public NetworkConnection(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        _networkName = networkName;

        NetResource netResource = new NetResource();
        netResource.Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork;
        netResource.ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk;
        netResource.DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share;
        netResource.RemoteName = networkName;

        int result = WNetAddConnection2(netResource, credentials.Password, credentials.UserName, 0);

        if (result != 0 && result != 1219)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
        }
    }

    ~NetworkConnection()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
    }

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource, string password, string username, int flags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags, bool force);
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NetResource
{
    public ResourceScope Scope;
    public ResourceType ResourceType;
    public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
    public int Usage;
    public string LocalName;
    public string RemoteName;
    public string Comment;
    public string Provider;
}

public enum ResourceScope : int
{
    Connected = 1,
    GlobalNetwork,
    Remembered,
    Recent,
    Context
};

public enum ResourceType : int
{
    Any = 0,
    Disk = 1,
    Print = 2,
    Reserved = 8
}

public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
{
    Generic = 0x0,
    Domain = 0x01,
    Server = 0x02,
    Share = 0x03,
    File = 0x04,
    Group = 0x05,
    Network = 0x06,
    Root = 0x07,
    Shareadmin = 0x08,
    Directory = 0x09,
    Tree = 0x0a,
    Ndscontainer = 0x0b
}
```

The exception occurs at the following line in Copy;

```
using (new NetworkConnection(destinationPath, cridentials))
```

When I tried to run the same copy code in a test application, it copied the file every time. Its only when I run it through the script that the exception occurs.

Does anyone have any idea to why this is?

Comment: Did you also try `CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE` instead of `0`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385427(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing for / closing any existing connections prior to opening a new one?

Comment: I tried removing the call to WNetCancelConnection2 in NetworkConnection's Dispose, which resulted in it working without any problems. So, If I cancel the connection, it gives me a "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated." error when I try to open a connection to the same computer a second time. I can't quite see why at the moment..