# WNetAddConnection2 does not work from Windows 2008 R2

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am trying to connect to a network location through my ASP.NET web application using WNetAddConnection2. Every thing works perfectly when I debug it using the ASP.NET Development Server provided along with VS2010. But when I deploy the code in a Windows Server 2008 R2 it does not place the file and throws a Win32 exception with error code 0X80004005. The application pool identity is network service and i am using a domain user account for imparsanation.

I have checked the connectivity and user name password validity using the command and it works pefectly from the server runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\User "explorer.exe \Path"

Please also note my firewall is switched off and i dont have an antivirus running on the Windows Server 2008.

Any help is really appreciated.

I have used the sample code from [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WNetUseConnection will work, we need to define all its structures properly. WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Windows Vista Windows Service behave security-wise differently and are not allowed any "desktop-related activity" (like mounting someting)...

ASP.NET runs under IIS which runs as a Service - what you try is not supported and can only be achieved by circumventing several issues with permissions etc.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve ?

Perhaps there is a different way to achieve that goal...

Comment: My ASP.NET application generates a CSV file which I need to drop to a network path (with specific permissions). The alternative is to create this CSV locally and another program (windows servive or a scheduled task console app) to pick this file and drop to the network location. Thought this is the easiest way - based on articles people got this working ...http://corner-house.blogspot.com/2006/03/accessing-shared-folders-in-aspnet.html

Comment: I understand that code but as I said: these things changed with Vista and if you don't want to mess seriously with the permissions you can't get it working this way... I would suggest to just generate the CSV, store it locally and whoever needs it can get via a HTTP URL / GET... this can be a scheduled job or whatever app that is really running outside a Service...

Comment: I have moved the code to a console application with scheduled task configured. However I see a intermittant behaviour with WNetAddConnection2. Is their any other way to connect to a network share? The code worked for once but after that it fails with the same error.

Comment: Any reason that drive is not just mapped once persistently via Windows Explorer and subsequently used by the console program ?

Comment: yes it is but then (when the user logged off) your console application isn't running either, or ? and when the user loggs on again the mapping is back - at least when you make is persistent...