# NetworkCredential doesn't work in IIS Server second request onwards

Tags: c#, networking, iis-7, asp.net-web-api2

I have developed a web API which works fine on the localhost. I have used the NetworkCrendential Class for accessing the shared folder files into my system. It is working fine for every request which I send while working on the localhost. But as soon as I deploy it on to the IIS web Server it is not able to get the data from the second request.

```
 using (NetworkConnection nc = new NetworkConnection(@"\\172.18.11.11\d$", new NetworkCredential(@"Administrator", "Siemens123$", "AD001")))
            {
                _listDataSetInfo = new List<DataSetInfo>();
                var folderPath_single = @"\\172.18.11.11\d$\BMC\_Settings\SINGLE";
                var items_single = new DataAccessLayer().GetData(folderPath_single);
                var folderPath_folder = @"\\172.18.11.11\d$\BMC\_Settings\FOLDER";
                var items_folder = new DataAccessLayer().GetData(folderPath_folder);
                foreach (var item in items_single)
                {
                    _listDataSetInfo.Add(item);
                }
                foreach (var item in items_folder)
                {
                    _listDataSetInfo.Add(item);
                }
                // _listDataSetInfo = new DataAccessLayer().GetData(folderPath_single);
                _CancellationToken = _CancellationTokenSource.Token;
                //nc.Dispose();
            }

public class NetworkConnection : IDisposable
{
    string _networkName;

    public NetworkConnection(string networkName,
        NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        _networkName = networkName;

        var netResource = new NetResource()
        {
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
            RemoteName = networkName
        };

        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
            ? credentials.UserName
            : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

        var result = WNetAddConnection2(
            netResource,
            credentials.Password,
            userName,
            0);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            NetworkConnection nc = new NetworkConnection(@"\\172.18.11.11\d$", new NetworkCredential(@"Administrator", "Siemens123$"));
            throw new Exception("Error connecting to remote share");
        }
    }

    ~NetworkConnection()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
    }

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,
        string password, string username, int flags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
        bool force);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NetResource
{
    public ResourceScope Scope;
    public ResourceType ResourceType;
    public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
    public int Usage;
    public string LocalName;
    public string RemoteName;
    public string Comment;
    public string Provider;
}

public enum ResourceScope : int
{
    Connected = 1,
    GlobalNetwork,
    Remembered,
    Recent,
    Context
};

public enum ResourceType : int
{
    Any = 0,
    Disk = 1,
    Print = 2,
    Reserved = 8,
}

public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
{
    Generic = 0x0,
    Domain = 0x01,
    Server = 0x02,
    Share = 0x03,
    File = 0x04,
    Group = 0x05,
    Network = 0x06,
    Root = 0x07,
    Shareadmin = 0x08,
    Directory = 0x09,
    Tree = 0x0a,
    Ndscontainer = 0x0b
}
```

Please provide some input that why this code is not working to get the data on the IIS Server while working fine on the localhost.

Comment: _"why this code is not working to get the data on the IIS Server while working fine on the localhost"_ - does this mean that on local host you are using not IIS, but another web server? Which one?

Comment: no with localhost also i'm using iisexpress so its all the same. I also cannot figure out where is the actual issue. is it with the code or within the server or could be a network issue. 
but first time it is giving me the data so it cannot be a network issue.
and since it is giving data so iis is also working fine I guess. But then why at the second request onwards it doesnt work.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268962/wnetaddconnection2-does-not-work-from-windows-2008-r2/7582359 , the title is a bit misleading but if you browse through the comments it is actually talking about the same situation (intermettent failure under IIS). Using WNetUseConnection solved it for them.

Comment: IIS Express and IIS are different things, so never say "it's all the same". You can find hints from https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 In your case, you are calling some Win32 API, so their behaviors can change when running on IIS.