# Copy files over network via file share, user authentication

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, impersonation, fileshare

I am building a .net C# console program to deploy file to a windows file share server (folder that is being shared). The path is :: `\\192.168.0.76\htdocs\public`

On running I am getting the error:

```
[09:35:29]: [Step 1/3] Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\192.168.0.76\htdocs\public' is denied.
[09:35:29]: [Step 1/3]    at DeployFileShare.Program.CopyDir(String source, String dest, String[] exclude, Boolean overwrite)
[09:35:29]: [Step 1/3]    at DeployFileShare.Program.Deploy(String num, String source)
[09:35:29]: [Step 1/3]    at DeployFileShare.Program.Main(String[] args)
[09:35:29]: [Step 1/3] Process exited with code -532459699
```

I think I need to authenticate myself. I've come across this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsIdentity idnt = new WindowsIdentity(username, password);
WindowsImpersonationContext context = idnt.Impersonate();
```

I've also tried:

```
AppDomain.CreateDomain("192.168.0.76").SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsIdentity idnt = new WindowsIdentity("user", "pass");
WindowsImpersonationContext context = idnt.Impersonate();
```

I am not sure how to use it. When I run the application I get:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>DeployFileShare 1 R:\BuildOutput\_PublishedWebsites\Web 2
1
Deploy Started Web, version 21
-- Deploy Prepared
-- Deploying to 1

Unhandled Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: There are currently no l
ogon servers available to service the logon request.

   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.KerbS4ULogon(String upn)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity..ctor(String sUserPrincipalName,
 String type)
   at DeployFileShare.Program.Authenticate(String server)
   at DeployFileShare.Program.Deploy(String num, String source)
   at DeployFileShare.Program.Main(String[] args)
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
```

Here is the basic code:

```
static void Main()
{
Copy();
}
static void Copy()
{
AppDomain.CreateDomain(GetServerInfo(server, "server")).SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
            WindowsIdentity idnt = new WindowsIdentity(GetServerInfo(server, "user"), GetServerInfo(server, "pass"));
            WindowsImpersonationContext context = idnt.Impersonate();
string source = "C:\\someDir";
string dest = "\\192.168.0.76\shareFolder"
string[] sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(source, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string file in sourceFiles)
            {
                string local = file.Replace(source, "");
                if (exclude.Contains(local))
                    continue;
                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(dest + "\\" + local)))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(dest + "\\" + local));
                File.Copy(file, dest + "\\" + local, overwrite);
                Console.WriteLine("-- -- [copied] {0} -> {1}", file, dest + "\\" + local);
            }
}
```

The code copy system in the for loop works, I've tested it on my local system.

If anyone knows how I should use WindowsIdentity and WindowsIdentity to get this to work please enlighten me. I've been looking around and window's documentation doesn't help much.

Basically how can I copy to a remote directory being shared by logging into the system?

Comment: You might want to consider using Powershell for this.  You can then just net use * \\192.168.9.76\ /USER:SomeUser <Password> prior to doing the copy (for which I would use Robocopy.exe ...)

Comment: @JamesJohnson I am using the IP because we are working with VMware and have the machine running this program under a different domain under VMware. So the computer name doesn't work.

Comment: I believe there is a more universal way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share/39540451#39540451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VB but easily translated to C#. Do this before your copy:

```
Private Sub Open_Remote_Connection(ByVal strComputer As String, ByVal strUserName As String, ByVal strPassword As String)
    Dim ProcessStartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    ProcessStartInfo.FileName = "net"
    ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "use \\" & strComputer & "\c$ /USER:" & strUsername & " " & strPassword
    ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to authenticate to a remote computer in order to move a file, you can use the [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to and WindowsIdentity to impersonate your user.

```
/// <summary>
/// Exécute une fonction en empruntant les credentials
/// </summary>
private T ApplyCredentials<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    IntPtr token;

    if (!LogonUser(
        _credentials.UserName,
        _credentials.Domain,
        _credentials.Password,
        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
        out token))
    {
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
    }

    try
    {
        // On doit être impersonifié seulement le temps d'ouvrir le handle.
        using (var identity = new WindowsIdentity(token))
        using (var context = identity.Impersonate())
        {
            return func();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseHandle(token);
    }
}

// ...

if (_credentials != null)
{
    return this.ApplyCredentials(() => File.Open(path, mode, access, share));
}

return File.Open(path, mode, access, share);
```