# How to download the files from different machines within the local network using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload

I have requirement where in i want to download the files from different machines within the local network using c#, later i will do certain processing on the downloaded files and i want to upload the files back to the respective machine from where i downloaded the files, please can i know what would be the best generic approach to achieve this.

Comment: download via ftp? via http? upload via ftp? via nfs? your question is too generic

Comment: Your question is too broad. Supply more details. Protocol you are using, your permissions, nature of you app.

Comment: I want to download and upload files using http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normal windows shares to accomplish this. Just share the folder and use the UNC Path to copy the file to and from. i.e.

```
//Copy From the share to the processing machine and swap the paths around to copy back
File.Copy(@"\\ComputerX\Share\MyFileToCopy.dat",@"c:\MyDumpFolder\MyCopiedFile.Dat");
```

if you need to authenticate first you can run the below method stub (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172079/copy-files-over-network-via-file-share-user-authentication) so question)

```
private void Open_Remote_Connection(string strComputer, string strUserName, string strPassword)
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ProcessStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    ProcessStartInfo.FileName = "net";
    ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "use \\\\" + strComputer + "\\c$ /USER:" + strUserName + " " + strPassword;
    ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if the files are just on there hard drive. Make the folder they are in a public drive then you can open the file using its address

Comment: Thanks for the reply , yes the files are placed in the public folders on the different machines which i am trying to access

Comment: @jonathan I write wrong comment on your last answer, so +1 on this one.