# network path not found

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I'm trying to send a file to one of our servers but I keeping getting the error "network path not found". Below is the code I'm using to send the file

```
         try
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading file to server....Please wait!!");
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, "domain");


            Uri address = new Uri(@"\\126.00.00.01\MyFolder\test.txt");

            client.Credentials = nc;

            string fullpath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filePath);

            byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(address, fullpath);
            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded sucessfully");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
```

Please what am I doing wrong. The server seems to work on windows explorer when test it.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: If you are trying to access your localhost with 126.00.00.01, perhaps try using the word localhost instead or 127.0.0.1, which are the correct references to your local machine.

Comment: Should it not be 126.0.0.1 rather than 126.00.00.01?

Comment: yea it is Bali but I still get the same error. And I'm doing this from a windows application

Comment: If it works fine for you via Windows explorer but not on another server, it must be either network access, or permissions surely?

Comment: Yes you are right Bridge, my WebClient as actually disabled. It worked as soon as I enabled it. Thanks everyone for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

[How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share) - Look at the answer

You cant use a WebClient to write a file to a UNC Path