# Get file to FileStream from remote path with another user credentials

Tags: c#, filestream, credentials

In my application I use `FileStream` to read from a file, that is on the fileshare somewhere in the network. So my `remoteFilePath` variable is something like: `\\computername\folder\file.pdf`

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(remoteFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 1024 * 1024)
```

Unfortunately, the user that I'm running this application with (that I'm logged into the PC with) does not have access to this fileshare. I have another user (domain, login & password), that has access to those files.

Is it possible to use the other user credentials to get a file to filestream? Can I impersonate the user **only** to get a file, and then continue with my own user?

Comment: Similar thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share

Comment: Much as I hate to post a link http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/ Has a great bit of code to use.

Comment: It seems like this is all you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share/1197430#1197430

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. Since the share was in another domain, it was not so easy to impersonate.

I found another, easier solution. I mapped a network drive, and checked the option `Connect using different credentials`. Then I connect to this drive instead of the remote path.

```
string mappedFilePath = filePath.Replace(@"\\computername\", @"Y:\")
```

and use this new string in `FileStream` constructor.

Comment: Can you please explain the operation more specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You should use impersonation.
More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx