# Allow access to folder using C# via Active Directory user and Restrict access using windows explorer

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, windows

I have some complex need basically related to Active Directory settings.

I have Shared Folder on Server.

We have software installed on the client machines. Now when client save the file, it should be save to the server machine's folder.

I have given Write Access to this folder and the file is being stored properly.

If I restrict View access then I can't see list of the files from the application.

If I am retrieving through the C# program then it should be retrieved. And if I see from the windows explorer then it should not be listed.

In short I want that the file read/write should be accessible from software only, but not from windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for impersonation. More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Similar thread: [Get file to FileStream from remote path with another user credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001972/get-file-to-filestream-from-remote-path-with-another-user-credentials)