# impersonate multiple users at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation

I'm making a service in .net that copy files from one domain (Domain A) to other domain (Domain B)
both domain need credentials in order to connect to them so i'm using impersonation.

```
using (new Impersonator(usr_name_source, domain_source, password_source))
```

the impersonation is working only for one domain each time, so actually i cannot work how to impersonate both domains at the same time in order to copy the files
so i'm trying this:

```
using (new Impersonator(usr_name_source, domain_source, password_source))//server authentication
                                        {
                                            using (new Impersonator(usr_name_target, domain_target, password_target))//server authentication
                                            {
                                                DeleteOldFiles(targetPath);
                                                Copy(sourcePath, targetPath);
                                            }
                                        }
```

but its not working as when i impersonate the  inside `new Impersonator(usr_name_target, domain_target, password_target)`

it forget the outer impersonation.

does anyone has any idea how to do that without mapping drives etc...?

Comment: Why do you need to do nested impersonation? as you have found out you can't be two users at the same time. Why not do the operations in two steps? can't you login to the source directory and copy the files locally. Login to the destination directory and copy the files from local to destination?

Comment: Maybe by creating multiple threads....

Comment: yes i can but i'm talking here about big files - i don't want a middle storage between, i want to move from A to B straight. i also prefer not working with threads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only impersonate one user at a time, so your current solution will not work. Basically you are trying to connect to two different network resources. You can P/Invoke WNetAddConnection2 function to connect to network resource of different domain and perform operation as needed. See here for details on WNetAddConnection2: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx

Go through this post to see how you P/Invoke WNetAddConnection2: [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share)

Comment: Thanks Deepak - that really helped!