# File.Create Network Share Different credentials Overwriting

Tags: c#, credentials, network-shares

I am writing a windows application using C#. I have a requirement where the files uploaded into the windows form are to be saved into a network share but not all users can access the network share (*\\FileServer\SharedFolder*). Only one user ( *FileWriter*)has got read / write / execute permissions on this folder. The current user *EmployeeUser* does not have any permissions on this share. I have verified this by opening the *Start->Run* *\\FileServer\SharedFolder*. This gives a Access Denied error box.

I have used [this example from SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share), using the `WNetAddConnection2` to connect with different credentials of *FileWriter* to save the file *Sample.txt* using **File.Create**. So far everything was OK.`WNetCancelConnection2` is called, I have verified in the code debug, and the program exited. Now from the current user, I have opened **StartMenu --> Run** and typed the *\\FileServer\SharedFolder* and the share immediately opened even though the windows user is *EmployeeUser*. I have closed the explorer and after a few minutes (this changes randomly through attempts) I have opened the *Start->Run* *\\FileServer\SharedFolder*. Now it gives a Access Denied error box.

**I am unable to understand this, Any help on this is much appreciated.**

Now after the Access Denied box I run the program again with the same steps except that the **Sample.txt** (using File.Create) is silently Overwritten. Isn't it supposed to give a File Exists Error?

Comment: What value is `WNetCancelConnection2` returning when called?

Comment: The [documentation for `File.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says "if the specified file does not exist, it is created; if it does exist and it is not read-only, the contents are overwritten."

Comment: @stuartd The `WNetCancelConnection2` is returning 0. Also thanks for the `File.Create`. I have completely forgotten that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a impersonator instead:

```
using (var impersonator = new Impersonator(username, password))
{
    File.Copy(source, destination, true);
}
```

this is a copy past from our implementation, so please adjust your domain name

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

public class Impersonator : IDisposable
{
/// <summary>
///     The Impersonator class is used to access a network share with other credentials.
/// </summary>
private readonly WindowsImpersonationContext _impersonatedUser;

private readonly IntPtr _userHandle;

/// <summary>
///     Constructor
/// </summary>
/// <param name="username">The user of the network share</param>
/// <param name="password">The password of the network share</param>
public Impersonator(string username, string password, string userDomain =   "YOURDOMAIN")
{
    _userHandle = new IntPtr(0);
    bool returnValue = LogonUser(username, userDomain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                                 ref _userHandle);
    if (!returnValue)
        throw new ApplicationException(
            "The applications wasn't able to impersonate the user with the specified credentials!");
    var newId = new WindowsIdentity(_userHandle);
    _impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
}

#region IDisposable Members

public void Dispose()
{
    if (_impersonatedUser != null)
    {
        _impersonatedUser.Undo();
        CloseHandle(_userHandle);
    }
}

#endregion

#region Interop imports/constants

public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
public const int LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 3;
public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUserName, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType,
                                    int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

#endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It worked beautifully. Now after the using block the _EmployeeUser_ is unable to browse the _\\FileServer\SharedFolder_, even if tried immediately. Your Solution Did solve my problem.

Comment: However, on a Side note I would like to know the problem  with `WNetCancelConnection2`, _Just for Educational Purpose, if not anything else_, which returned 0 but allowed the _EmployeeUser_ to browse the _\\FileServer\SharedFolder_ as pointed in my original post.

Comment: I don't know `WNetCancelConnection2`, never used it. sorry