# How to get remote folder names, select them and delete them in C#?

Tags: c#, directory, remote-access, delete-file, delete-directory

I am brand-new in C# and I wanna do that in C#.
Can you show me the way :)

- Enter a remote machine hostname
- get list folder names in C directory from the remote machine
- select folder names from the list
- delete the selected folders
- show a message about the process (deleted or not)

Is that too hard? Thank you for your help in advance and sory for my bad English :(

Comment: Unfortunately this is too broad for Stack Overflow. If you have problems with a specific issue, please show what you have tried and then others may be able to help you.

Comment: Sure. S Tart learning the language. Then read the relevant namespaces (Hm, folder - that sounds like System.IO) from the manual. What classes are there, what methods do exist. Then you are smarter. T His is the way people that want to be good do it.

Comment: Yes; you are right :( But I wanna learn :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A broad question, here are a few general answers.

> Enter a remote machine hostname

Set up a GUI for that (WinForms or whatever you like)

> get list folder names in C directory from the remote machine

Look into remote directory services, *especially* Samba / SMB setup and access for Windows. [This question will be usefull.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295703/5296568)

> select folder names from the list

With the appriopiate GUI elements (a `TreeView` maybe), easily possible.

> delete the selected folders

Issue a `File.Delete()` command for the appropiate path, see link above.

> show a message about the process (deleted or not)

Wrap above command in a `try-catch`, then call `MessageBox.Show()` or whatever GUI elements you want for that.

Answer (score 2):

Remote and local file system access in C# (.NET) works the same way. Try for example the following.

```
var directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("\\server\path\remote\C");
var files = directory.GetFiles();
foreach(var f in files) f.Delete();
```

For remote drives, for example drive C, the path will be like: \server\c$\folderUnderC (note the dollar sign).