# Remote Shared folders and drives C#

Tags: c#, networking

I want to access drives/folders/sub-folders/files on remote machines over network for a machine in C#.

I know of a using WMI for this. However WMI might not be executable over remote machines due to security permissions.

What are alternative way in C# to enumerate the folders/subfolders/files for remote machines over the network.

Thanks!
Gagan

Comment: By "remote machines", do you mean file shares (accessible by UNC paths, like \\machine\share\file.txt), FTP sites, or anything else?

Comment: Yes and paths like \\machine\C$. Is it possible to enumerate the folders and files on a network machine  if we are provided the credentials of the network machine.

Answer (score 8):

Shared folders on a UNC path can be enumerated just like local directories, using the classes in the System.IO [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), like `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\machine\c$"))
{
}
```

However, as you say, there's a question of credentials. If you need to specify different credentials to access the shares, you'll have to authenticate against the remote machine. Luckily, there's a great solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share/1197430#1197430) for creating ad-hoc network connections:

```
using (new NetworkConnection("\\machine\c$", new NetworkCredential("username", "password")))
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\machine\c$"))
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forfiles`, i am assuming all the machines are `Windows`.

Refer to this link for more information: [Forfiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(v=ws.11).aspx)