# Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password while creating folder in remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows-share

I'm trying to create a folder on remote machine (computer is in same network). I'm  using the code, when I try to excue the code, I'm getting following error message:

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Can any one suggest me how to create a folder on remote machine (which is in same network)?

[image]

```
string path = @"\\16.166.187.121\c$\testingfolder\Features\Temp\";
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: Has the user permission to create a directory on the remote share? I guess your path is wrong as well, it should be \c$\ instead \c$\\.

Comment: @hofmeister, user is having admin rights, I modified path correctly but still same issues I m facing

Answer (score 0):

i guess something is wrong with your credential.
take a look at here: [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share)

Comment: in the code no where I m providing user credentials to create folder in remote machine

Comment: all you need is to create your own NetworkConnection and use it in order to create directory.

Comment: I tried few networkConnections found in google when i try to use those i m getting error code 53 .