# C# Connect to Remote machine and move the file between folders

Tags: c#, file, remote-access

I have tried to move the files between the folder in remote machine by using the IP address:

```
string sourcFile, destinationFile;
sourcFile = @"\\IPaddress\\Image\\IDM17-02-20-18-29.txt";
destinationFile = @"\\IPaddress\\data\\IDM17-01-03-15-36.txt";
File.Move(sourcFile, destinationFile);
```

but I have faced the following issue while running the code:

> unknown username and bad password

How to pass the credential to connect to the remote machine ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share)

Comment: The remote machine in work group, so can i used the work group name as a parameter instead of domain name.