# How to resolve this error "ERROR_BAD_USERNAME" in WNetAddConnection2?

Tags: c#, io, networkcredentials, wnet

My problem is to copy file from one system to another system on the same network. I googled for the above problem, I started working with [Mark Brackett's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share) answer.

Now i am planning to copy the files from my system to another system, but i am getting following error codes 53, 67, 2202. I resolved the first two error codes successfully. Now i am stuck with 2202. please look into the below code.

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"\\192.168.0.110\", "krishna4");

private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
// NetwrokConnection(string networkName, NetworkCredential credentials)
        using (new NetworkConnection("\\\\10.235.115.210\\d", credentials)) ; 
        System.IO.File.Copy("D:\\English\\parts.oxps", @"\\192.168.0.110\test\parts.oxps", true);
    }
```

Please help to resolve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ,My answer is useful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your connection credentials may be wrong.it may be invalid user name.

I suggest to refer following link:

[ERROR_BAD_USERNAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx)

[WNetUseConnection2 in C#](https://gist.github.com/AlanBarber/92db36339a129b94b7dd)

[How to finish this implementation of creating a network share using WNetAddConnection2?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9fc8adce-cc36-4e4a-96e9-fbf5a5b04a5a/how-to-finish-this-implementation-of-creating-a-network-share-using-wnetaddconnection2?forum=csharpgeneral)

> ERROR_BAD_USERNAME :The specified user name is not valid.

Here is Sample Code;

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;    

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          var networkPath = @"//server/share";
          var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

          using (new NetworkConnection(networkPath, credentials))
          {
            var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(networkPath);
          }

          foreach (var file in fileList)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("{0}", Path.GetFileName(file));
          }          
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Anjali,I hope this answer useful for you!