# Access a file on local area network with authorization c#

Tags: c#, file, networking, lan

I want to access a file on a different machine that is on the same network as me. I also need to authenticate when doing this.

For Example;

```
My Local IP : 10.1.1.138
Target Local IP: 10.1.1.235
File Location is \\10.1.1.235\FolderName\example.txt

Username for target machine is: "username"
Password for target machine is: "password"
```

I want to do like this:

```
string data = File.GetAllText(@"\\10.1.1.235\FolderName\example.txt");   //with authentication
```

How can i do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share

Comment: If file/folder is made shared you may already have authorization.

Comment: File wasn't made by me and I want to authentication