# How to save files in a folder that is protected by username and password in c #

Tags: c#

How can I save a file to a folder that is protected?
How do I add the user and password to my route so I can save a file?
For example, C: \ Desktop \ Folder
When I try to open the folder, it asks for a username and password, how can I authenticate from the code?

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(STORAGE_ROOT, Path.GetFileName(fileInfo.fileId));
file.SaveAs(fullPath);
return fileInfo;
```

In `STORAGE_ROOT`, I have saved the path of the folder
And in `Path.GetFileName (fileInfo.fileId)`, I have the file.

Comment: how was the folder created?

Comment: It is a folder created manually by a user in a specific directory. I have to save in that folder.

Comment: so a standard folder? is the user running the program have permission to it?

Comment: The code has explicit a user variable and password with the data to access that folder.
I do not know how the code passes those variables to the folder to authenticate

 In the future you will get the user and password from a database.

Comment: Windows only limit access to (local) filesystems by means of file/folder permissions, not by an extra user/password. Neither Windows has any concept of "protected" data, beyond file permissions. How are you getting such a prompt? By using an external program? Or by using a network share?

Comment: It is using a shared network.
When I open the folder on my computer it shows me a Windows Security window where user / password is requested. 
When my code calls the folder, it will ask to authenticate...

Comment: Access denied to the path \\ channels1 \ datafile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share)