# How to access a password protected file from the network share?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck with a problem where I have to get the contents (files and sub-directories) of a password protected folder from Network shared location.
Given, I have the password to access the folder and the file path to get to that location. How can I implement this?

Suppose, this is the shared network-
\Server\Sharedfiles\PasswordProtectedFolder
I want to get the list of contents in it.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share

Comment: @NevilleKuyt That's it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to access files form UNC path.

```
    public static class NetworkShare
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Connects to the remote share
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Null if successful, otherwise error message.</returns>
        public static string ConnectToShare(string uri, string username, string password)
        {
            //Create netresource and point it at the share
            var nr = new Netresource
            {
                dwType = ResourcetypeDisk,
                lpRemoteName = uri
            };

            //Create the share
            var ret = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);

            //Check for errors
            return ret == NoError ? null : GetError(ret);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove the share from cache.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Null if successful, otherwise error message.</returns>
        public static string DisconnectFromShare(string uri, bool force)
        {
            //remove the share
            var ret = WNetCancelConnection(uri, force);

            //Check for errors
            return ret == NoError ? null : GetError(ret);
        }

        #region P/Invoke Stuff
        [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
            IntPtr hwndOwner,
            Netresource lpNetResource,
            string lpPassword,
            string lpUserId,
            int dwFlags,
            string lpAccessName,
            string lpBufferSize,
            string lpResult
            );

        [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection(
            string lpName,
            bool fForce
            );

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private class Netresource
        {
            public int dwScope = 0;
            public int dwType = 0;
            public int dwDisplayType = 0;
            public int dwUsage = 0;
            public string lpLocalName = "";
            public string lpRemoteName = "";
            public string lpComment = "";
            public string lpProvider = "";
        }

        #region Consts
        const int ResourcetypeDisk = 0x00000001;
        const int ConnectUpdateProfile = 0x00000001;
        #endregion

        #region Errors
        const int NoError = 0;

        const int ErrorAccessDenied = 5;
        const int ErrorAlreadyAssigned = 85;
        const int ErrorBadDevice = 1200;
        const int ErrorBadNetName = 67;
        const int ErrorBadProvider = 1204;
        const int ErrorCancelled = 1223;
        const int ErrorExtendedError = 1208;
        const int ErrorInvalidAddress = 487;
        const int ErrorInvalidParameter = 87;
        const int ErrorInvalidPassword = 1216;
        const int ErrorMoreData = 234;
        const int ErrorNoMoreItems = 259;
        const int ErrorNoNetOrBadPath = 1203;
        const int ErrorNoNetwork = 1222;
        const int ErrorSessionCredentialConflict = 1219;

        const int ErrorBadProfile = 1206;
        const int ErrorCannotOpenProfile = 1205;
        const int ErrorDeviceInUse = 2404;
        const int ErrorNotConnected = 2250;
        const int ErrorOpenFiles = 2401;

        private struct ErrorClass
        {
            public int Num;
            public string Message;
            public ErrorClass(int num, string message)
            {
                this.Num = num;
                this.Message = message;
            }
        }

        private static readonly ErrorClass[] ErrorList = new ErrorClass[] {
        new ErrorClass(ErrorAccessDenied, "Error: Access Denied"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorAlreadyAssigned, "Error: Already Assigned"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorBadDevice, "Error: Bad Device"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorBadNetName, "Error: Bad Net Name"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorBadProvider, "Error: Bad Provider"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorCancelled, "Error: Cancelled"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorExtendedError, "Error: Extended Error"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorInvalidAddress, "Error: Invalid Address"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorInvalidParameter, "Error: Invalid Parameter"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorInvalidPassword, "Error: Invalid Password"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorMoreData, "Error: More Data"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorNoMoreItems, "Error: No More Items"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorNoNetOrBadPath, "Error: No Net Or Bad Path"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorNoNetwork, "Error: No Network"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorBadProfile, "Error: Bad Profile"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorCannotOpenProfile, "Error: Cannot Open Profile"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorDeviceInUse, "Error: Device In Use"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorExtendedError, "Error: Extended Error"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorNotConnected, "Error: Not Connected"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorOpenFiles, "Error: Open Files"),
        new ErrorClass(ErrorSessionCredentialConflict, "Error: Credential Conflict"),
    };

        private static string GetError(int errNum)
        {
            foreach (var er in ErrorList)
            {
                if (er.Num == errNum) return er.Message;
            }
            return "Error: Unknown, " + errNum;
        }
        #endregion

        #endregion

        public static byte[] GetFileBytes(string serverSharedPath,string fileName, string userName, string password)
        {
            DisconnectFromShare($@"{serverSharedPath}", true); //Disconnect in case we are currently connected with our credentials;
            var connectToShare = ConnectToShare($@"{serverSharedPath}", userName, password); //Connect with the new credentials
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectToShare))
                return new byte[0];
            if (!Directory.Exists($@"{serverSharedPath}"))
                return new byte[0];
            if (!File.Exists($@"{serverSharedPath}\{fileName}"))
                return new byte[0];
            return File.ReadAllBytes(
                $@"{serverSharedPath}\{fileName}");
        }

        public static bool DeleteFileFromSharedPath(string serverSharedPath, string fileName, string userName,
            string password)
        {
            DisconnectFromShare($@"{serverSharedPath}", true); //Disconnect in case we are currently connected with our credentials;
            var connectToShare = ConnectToShare($@"{serverSharedPath}", userName, password); //Connect with the new credentials
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectToShare))
                return false;
            if (File.Exists($@"{serverSharedPath}\{fileName}"))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete($@"{serverSharedPath}\{fileName}");
                    return true;
                }
                catch (IOException exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public static bool WriteFileByte(string serverSharedPath, string fileName, byte[] fileBytes, string userName, string password)
        {
            DisconnectFromShare($@"{serverSharedPath}",
                true); //Disconnect in case we are currently connected with our credentials;
            var connectToShare =
                ConnectToShare($@"{serverSharedPath}", userName, password); //Connect with the new credentials
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectToShare))
                return false;
            if (!Directory.Exists($@"{serverSharedPath}"))
                return false;
            if (File.Exists($@"{serverSharedPath}\{fileName}"))
                File.Delete($@"{serverSharedPath}\{fileName}");

            File.WriteAllBytes($@"{serverSharedPath}\{fileName}", fileBytes);
            return true;
        }


        public static bool IsNetworkConnectivityOk(string serverSharedPath, string userName, string password)
        {
            DisconnectFromShare($@"{serverSharedPath}", true); //Disconnect in case we are currently connected with our credentials;
            var connectToShare = ConnectToShare($@"{serverSharedPath}", userName, password); //Connect with the new credentials
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectToShare))
                return false;
            if (!Directory.Exists($@"{serverSharedPath}"))
                return false;
            DisconnectFromShare($@"{serverSharedPath}", false); //Disconnect from the server.
            return true;
        }
    }
```