# Azure API App connect to on-prem fileshare

Tags: c#, azure

I need to connect to a fileshare on an onprem IBM i-series server from am API App in Azure using a given set of credentials.

I´m currently using:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a

With implementation according to:
[How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share/1197430#1197430)

This solution works just fine when the code is running localy but from Azure I always get a System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

The API App is running in an App Service Environment and the port 445 is open according to the azure infra team.

Does anyone have any tips on how to either change the code to make it work or build the solution some other way?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have 2fa? That can be your issue.