# How to use network shared path with credentials as static files folder in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to serve the static images from a network shared path, but when I map this path middleware, it is throwing exception as this path cannot access in middleware. Please let me know how to map a static files from network shared folder with credentials.
I am using following code

```
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                            Path.Combine("\\sharedfolder\images")

            });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution from the given hint by @Stefano, thanks.

```
NetworkCredential sourceCredentials = new NetworkCredential { Domain = "domain", UserName = "user", Password = "pass" };

using (new NetworkConnection("\\\\networkpath\\Shared", sourceCredentials))
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine("\\\\networkpath\\Shared"))
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you importing `NetworkConnection`? i get and error when I copy and paste this. `'NetworkConnection' is a namespace but is used like a type`

Comment: I have added code for NetworkConnection class, please include into your project.

Answer (score 1):

@Manoj, you can use the following class.

```
   public class NetworkConnection : IDisposable
{
    string _networkName;
   
    public NetworkConnection(string networkName,
        NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        _networkName = networkName;

        var netResource = new NetResource()
        {
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
            RemoteName = networkName
        };

        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
            ? credentials.UserName
            : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

        var result = WNetAddConnection2(
            netResource,
            credentials.Password,
            userName,
            0);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
        }
    }

    ~NetworkConnection()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
    }

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,
        string password, string username, int flags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
        bool force);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NetResource
{
    public ResourceScope Scope;
    public ResourceType ResourceType;
    public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
    public int Usage;
    public string LocalName;
    public string RemoteName;
    public string Comment;
    public string Provider;
}

public enum ResourceScope : int
{
    Connected = 1,
    GlobalNetwork,
    Remembered,
    Recent,
    Context
};

public enum ResourceType : int
{
    Any = 0,
    Disk = 1,
    Print = 2,
    Reserved = 8,
}

public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
{
    Generic = 0x0,
    Domain = 0x01,
    Server = 0x02,
    Share = 0x03,
    File = 0x04,
    Group = 0x05,
    Network = 0x06,
    Root = 0x07,
    Shareadmin = 0x08,
    Directory = 0x09,
    Tree = 0x0a,
    Ndscontainer = 0x0b
}
```