# Accessing protected directories with ASP.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, directory, data-protection

I would like to create a password protected directory on the remote webserver and have my webapp access that folder as a ‘user’ and be able to read and write. I assume I need a method that can include a username/password for that specific directory?

Is there a recommended way to do that?

I have looked at the ‘`DirectoryInfo`’ and ‘`FileInfo`’ methods, but I cannot find anything on this subject. I have looked at several threads about `WnetAddConnection2`, but I cannot make heads or tails out of these suggestions, as they focus on creating a Share in Windows, more than just allowing access. I am looking for something in near code as:
`saveFile (name=xyz) to directoryPath(name, accessCredentials)`

I run my ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web Application on a externally hosted environment. One of the features of the app is to upload documents to a directory (folder).

The current setup of my hosting provider allows anonymous to access those documents through a browser (e.g. (www.mydomain.com/securedocs/thisdoc.txt). The hostingprovider does allow for a password-protected directory. I have created such a directory.

EDIT:
The directories are located under HttpDocs/wwwroot/ on a webserver, hosted by an external hostingprovider.

Comment: Something like in this url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/295703/5632166 (this is logging into a network share)

Comment: @lordvlad30 I will try, but I have my doubts. That solution is about creating a network share. The protected directory is on the web server and I do not need to create the share. Keep you posted.

Comment: The link is about connecting to a network share. Maybe just adjusting the address will work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change directory permission in Windows.

You can set with which user your application will run in IIS.

So you don't have to care about username and password in your application, just ensure the user that IIS run your application, is able to read and write to this folder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I do not  fully understand your answer. How do I set with which user my application will run in IIS? I have only Plesk to manage my hostingenvironment. Should the protected directory have the same credentials?

Comment: Do you have access to the server?

Comment: I can reach the server through Plex

Comment: Plex is not a media server?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I host my website through a hostingprovider. The folders are located on that server, which -I presume-  is a webserver.