# System.MissingMethodException: cannot use dirInfo.GetAccessControl(); in c#

Tags: c#, permissions, acl

## Issue:

I am following the [microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8) in order to set directory permissions on a network share.

Despite the Intellicode not showing any issue, I receive the following error as soon as a function is called which contains `dirInfo.GetAccessControl();`

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl()'.'

The function to execute is as follows:

```
public static void SetFullPermission(string path, string domainAccount)
{
    NTAccount ntaccount = new NTAccount("my_domain", domainAccount);
    var ds = new DirectorySecurity();
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    ds = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();
    ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(ntaccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
    ds.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false); // disable inheritance and clear any inherited permissions
    dirInfo.SetAccessControl(ds);
}
```

As soon as I uncomment the line `var ds = new DirectorySecurity();` the code gets executed but no permissions are set.

## Code reference

For reference, the following code might be useful. The calling code looks like the following:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my_admin",pwd);
using (new NetworkConnection(@"\\my_fileserver\Data\Home", cred))
{
    string path = $@"\\my_fileserver\Data\Home\testuserfolder";
    string domainName = "my_domain";
    string userNameToCreate = "testuser";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    SetFullPermission(path, userNameToCreate);
}
```

The code which calls `SetFullPermission` utilizes a class found in [How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share) because my normal account has no permissions on the network drive.

The class `NewNetworkConnection()` is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FileInterface
{
    public class NetworkConnection : IDisposable
    {
        string _networkName;

        public NetworkConnection(string networkName,
            NetworkCredential credentials)
        {
            _networkName = networkName;

            var netResource = new NetResource()
            {
                Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
                ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
                DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
                RemoteName = networkName
            };

            var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
                ? credentials.UserName
                : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

            var result = WNetAddConnection2(
                netResource,
                credentials.Password,
                userName,
                0);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(result);
            }
        }

        ~NetworkConnection()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
        }

        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,
            string password, string username, int flags);

        [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
            bool force);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class NetResource
    {
        public ResourceScope Scope;
        public ResourceType ResourceType;
        public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
        public int Usage;
        public string LocalName;
        public string RemoteName;
        public string Comment;
        public string Provider;
    }

    public enum ResourceScope : int
    {
        Connected = 1,
        GlobalNetwork,
        Remembered,
        Recent,
        Context
    };

    public enum ResourceType : int
    {
        Any = 0,
        Disk = 1,
        Print = 2,
        Reserved = 8,
    }

    public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
    {
        Generic = 0x0,
        Domain = 0x01,
        Server = 0x02,
        Share = 0x03,
        File = 0x04,
        Group = 0x05,
        Network = 0x06,
        Root = 0x07,
        Shareadmin = 0x08,
        Directory = 0x09,
        Tree = 0x0a,
        Ndscontainer = 0x0b
    }
}
```

## Solution reference

The following solution information might be important:

- The solution has a main project `Ticketing solution` targeting `.NET Core`
- The project where the issues code relies in is a `.NET Framework` class library targeting `.NET framework 4.8`

[image]

The reason for the different framework targets is that some code requires the one framework, other code or reference might only work with the other.

Answer (score 2):

In a Multi-Target Solution, the .net core code must be used, eventhough the target is .Net Framework 4.8:

change the `GetAccessControl` and `SetAccesscontrol` (see uncommented lines for difference)

```
public static void SetFullPermission(string path, string domainAccount)
{
    NTAccount ntaccount = new NTAccount("skan_nt1", domainAccount);
    var ds = new DirectorySecurity();
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    ds = FileSystemAclExtensions.GetAccessControl(dirInfo);
    //ds = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();
    ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(ntaccount, FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
    ds.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false); // disable inheritance and clear any inherited permissions
    FileSystemAclExtensions.SetAccessControl(dirInfo,ds);
    //Directory.SetAccessControl(path, ds);
}
```

additionally, make sure nuget package is installed: `System.Security.AccessControl`