# Windows Server 2016 is denying me access to create a Folder using C#

Tags: c#, directory

I'm trying to create a Folder on a Win Server 2016 (on VM Ware) using C#. Below are my lines of code:

```
NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
CredentialCache theNetcache = new CredentialCache();
theNetcache.Add(new Uri(@"\\WIN-FM8PGNEC4OF\"), "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
string subdir = @"\\WIN-FM8PGNEC4OF\Archives\BN\" + entity + "\\" + folder;
if (!Directory.Exists(subdir))
{
   try
   {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(subdir);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      return;
   }
}
```

I have granted full permission (read/write) to Everyone to the main folder called Archives, which my application uses for creating directories. I've also disabled anti-virus, disabled firewall. But the code keeps giving me exception of incorrect username or password. I've pinged the server using its name (WIN-FM8PGNEC4OF) and i get a positive response. What is funny though is, when I try to access the shared folder via run (Win + R), after prompt for username and password, I gain access via explorer, AS WELL AS THE APPLICATION STOPPED THROWING EXCEPTION (meaning the application creates the directory successfully). Please help me out from my misery.

Comment: I guess you have to use `NTLM` instead of `Basic` Authentication

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share/1197430#1197430