# Accessing Network Share Folders in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, shared-directory

Is there a way to access the network share folder with the provided credentials in flutter?

I've tried using the Uri's constructor to pass in the credentials but I'm met with an error saying that they are invalid.

```
  final uri = Uri(
    scheme: "file",
    host: 'ipaddress',
    path: 'filepath',
    userInfo: "username:password",
  );

  final file = File.fromUri(uri);
  //Error thrown when trying to read file
```

Comment: https://medium.flutterdevs.com/sharing-files-in-flutter-66aa4e115256 Read this

Comment: Hey @MobinAnsar thanks for the link but this is not what I'm looking for. 
Sorry for not making it more clear in the post but I'm looking for something similar to C#'s way of accessing network drives (Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39540451)